How to properly control page break in printing feature of mozilla firefox?
I have a problem with page breaks and tables on Mozilla firefox. I want to allow page break in the first table (.infobox) and it doesn't work :
table : should have break
Image: table not appearing right
And I also want to forbid page break between h2 and tables, here I have the title Construction and a table bellow it :
Construction : shouldn't have break
Image: Construction not appearing right
(the problem appears only on mozilla firefox, maybe because of the headers and footer added)
Here's a sample html of what the page looks like :
<body>
  <div class="wrapper column">
    <header id="site-header" class="site-header"></header>
    <div id="header-image">
      <div class="article-tabs">...</div>  <!-- hidden for pinting -->
      <div id="header-image2" class="" style="background-image:...;"></div> <!-- height:0 when in printing -->
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="mw-body ve-init-mw-desktopArticleTarget-targetContainer has-archi-columns" role="main">
      <div id="contentSub">...</div> <!-- France > Strasbourg ... -->
      <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">...</h1> <!--  big title of the page -->
      <div class="mw-info-column">
        <div id="infobox-div-print">
          <img id="header-image-print" src="..." style="min-width:0px;height:fit-content;">
          <table class="infobox">
            <tbody>...</tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="toc" class="toc" role="navigation">...></div> <!-- Sommaire -->
        <div class="translations">...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mw-content-column">
        ...
        <div id="bodyContent" class="mw-body-content">
          <ul class="archi-wiki-toolbox"></ul>
          <div id="mw-content-text" class="mw-body-content mw-content-ltr">
            <div class="mw-parser-output">
              <p class="noexcerpt"></p>
              <div class="thumb tright" style="display:none;">...</div>
              <p></br></p>
              <h2>
                <span id="Universitäts- und Landesbibliothek puis BNU"></span>
                <span id="Universitäts- und Landesbibliothek puis BNU">
                  <i>Universitäts- und Landesbibliothek</i> puis BNU
                </span>
                <span class="mw-editsection">...</span> <!-- hidden for pinting -->
              </h2>
              <table class="infobox-actu">...</table>
              ...
              ...
          

Here's the default printing css of mediawiki source code :
@media print {
  * {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: black !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important; }
  pre,
  blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #8a8a8a;
    page-break-inside: avoid; }
  thead {
    display: table-header-group; }
  tr,
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid; }
  img {
    max-width: 100% !important; }
  @page {
    margin: 0.5cm; }
  p,
  h2,
  h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3; }
  h2,
  h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid; } }

Here's the css I added :
@media print {
  #site-header, .translations, #mw-data-after-content,#mw-footer,.mw-editsection,.leaflet-control,.article-tabs,.archi-wiki-toolbox {
    display: none; }
  a{
    text-decoration: underline !important;
  }
  .reference a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }
  #toc{
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  } 
  a[href*="archive"],a[title*="Actualités"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
  h3{
    border-bottom-style: solid !important;
  }
  .infobox{
    margin-top:0px !important;
  }
  @media (orientation: portrait) {
    .infobox {
      width: 50% !important;
      max-width: 50% !important;
      min-width: 50% !important;
    }
  }

  @media (orientation: landscape) {
    .infobox {
      width: 30% !important;
      max-width: 30% !important;
      min-width: 30% !important;
    }
  }
  #header-image{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    height: 0px;
  }
  #infobox-div-print{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
  table.infobox,div.mw-info-column,div#infobox-div-print{
    page-break-inside: unset !important;
  }
  table.infobox-actu {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    page-break-before: avoid !important;
  }
  h2,h3, h2 span,h3 span, h2 span:first-child.mw-headline, h3 span:first-child.mw-headline {
    page-break-after: avoid !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }
}

Here's some js to place things at the right place :
addEventListener("beforeprint", function() {
    var UrlImage = $('#header-image2').css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
    $(".infobox").wrap('<div id="infobox-div-print"></div>');
    $("#infobox-div-print").prepend('<img src="'+UrlImage+'" id="header-image-print" style="min-width:0px; height:fit-content;">');
    $('#firstHeading').insertBefore('.mw-info-column');
    $('#contentSub').insertBefore('#firstHeading');
    console.log(UrlImage);
});
addEventListener("afterprint", function() {
    $("#header-image-print").remove();
    $('#firstHeading').insertBefore('#siteSub');
    $('#contentSub').insertBefore('#firstHeading');
    $(".infobox").unwrap();

});

